# Get top N largest rows of every group in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

i have a dataframe

```
val1    val1     distance
100      200      1.5
100      300       5.2
100      234       3.7
200      100       1.6
200      600       4.8
```

i want to find Top 2 distance rows for every `val1`.
i'e

for every `val1` get the top 2 minimum distance rows

```
   val1  val2  distance
0   100   200       1.5
2   100   234       3.7
3   200   100       1.6
4   200   600       4.8
```

this is just a sample dataset( i actually have around 1000 unique val1)
Therefore i thought grouping by val1 is not a good idea.

Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: And on what premise are you filling in `val2`. Randomly?

Comment: Also, why does `val1 == 200` only have one row showing?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It is not random, for val = 100, sort by distance column and get the top 2 rows .
also it may happen that for val==200, there is only 1 row, and you are finding top 2 rows, it should not show error but give that 1 row.

my point was, in future , i could be able to change the `n`

Comment: Ok, but `val1` has 2 rows having `200`, so getting the "top 2" should be possible since there are 2 rows? Or am I misunderstanding something? It seems like `df.sort_values(['val1', 'distance']).groupby('val1').head(2)` would solve this problem, but I'm a little confused by your output.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That workeed!

Comment: The advantage of `groupby.head` is its immense flexibility with specifying N. Also, if there are less than N rows, then there is no error raised. Happy coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I was overanalysing your question, but a simple `sort_values`, followed by `groupby` + `head` should give you what you need.

```
df.sort_values(['val1', 'distance']).groupby('val1').head(2)

   val1  val2  distance
0   100   200       1.5
2   100   234       3.7
3   200   100       1.6
4   200   600       4.8
```

If you need more than 2, just change the argument to `head`. Also, if, for example, you call `head(2)` and there is only one row, then that single row is returned (without any issues).